# How to avoid duplication in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner here and I managed to modify a code to extract data from a sheet and copy and paste them to other sheets. Problem is when I click run Macro or the button assigned to the Macro, it is duplicating rows again. Please help me to avoid the duplication.

TIA

```
Sub UpdateHistory()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsCostCode As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, NextRow As Long, i As Long
Dim CostCode As String
Dim Company As String
Dim Invoice As String
Dim Price As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsData = Sheets("Signed Invoices")
LastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    CostCode = wsData.Range("A" & i).Value
    Company = wsData.Range("B" & i).Value
    Invoice = wsData.Range("C" & i).Value
    Total = wsData.Range("D" & i).Value
    
    If WorksheetExists(CostCode) = True Then
        Set wsCostCode = Sheets(CostCode)
        NextRow = wsCostCode.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsCostCode.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = CostCode
        wsCostCode.Range("B" & NextRow).Value = Company
        wsCostCode.Range("C" & NextRow).Value = Invoice
        wsCostCode.Range("D" & NextRow).Value = Total
    Else
        wsData.Range("A1:D1").Copy
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = CostCode
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = CostCode
        ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = Company
        ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = Invoice
        ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value = Total
    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Signed Invoices").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
On Error GoTo 0
WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you find that your code isn't doing what you expect, try stepping through it line-by-line and see exactly where and when it goes wrong.  You can do this by pressing `F8` while your cursor is anywhere in your macro.  I also recommend commenting out `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` until your code is working as expected.  Otherwise, following the code's behavior can become difficult when the code is supposed to write things to worksheets.

You've found that your code is duplicating entries.  Let's check all places in your macro that write data to the sheet.  There is only one place: inside your `For i = 2 to LastRow` loop.  Because you have set up a loop, you are expecting (or at least preparing) for this block of code to run more than once.  The next question should be, why is the data not changing between two iterations like you're expecting?

Check that `Else` block of code.  It seems like you copy the headers, add a new sheet, and then use the `ActiveSheet` to specify which sheet to write the data.  Is `ActiveSheet` the sheet you think it is?  (Very easy to verify with line-by-line debugging.)  If you really want to use `ActiveSheet`, make sure the sheet you expect to be active **is** active with `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Activate`.  This will activate the last worksheet, which is where you want to write your data.

Try stepping line-by-line through your code and see if this is correct before modifying your code.